# pass sql query as a string from one jsp page to another

Tags: java, jsp

I've two jsp pages one is `b.jsp` and the other `query.jsp`.In `b.jsp` i have created a function `select` which returns an arraylist `rows` to `query.jsp`.
Arraylist `rows` includes some database values of `testemployee` table executing the query `"select * from testemployee";`.From `query.jsp` I have called `select` function as

```
<%
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(select());      
    %>
```

My previous code was in `b.jsp`

```
<%!
      String query;
  %>
  <%!
  public List select() {
    List rows = new ArrayList();
    Map row = null;


    try {
        query="select * from testemployee";
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
 %>
```

It was working perfect.Now i am trying to execute queries dynamically ,i want to pass the sql query as a string from `query.jsp` to `b.jsp` for execution.I don't want to keep the query static in b.jsp.

Now i have modified my code.I've added a String variable `query` in `query.jsp` page and write my query as `query="select * from testemployee";` and tried to pass the query to b.jsp page as

```
 <%
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(select(query));      
   %>
```

But it is not working.How should i pass the query as a string from `query.jsp` and get the list returned from `b.jsp`.Please consider my question.
Below is my code

`query.jsp`

```
<%@page import="com.google.gson.Gson"%>
<%@include file="b.jsp"%>
<%
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(select(query));      
    %>
```

`b.jsp`

```
    <%!
   Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
%>
<%
    try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test", "postgres", "root");
    statement = connection.createStatement();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
%>
<%!
  public List select(String query) {
    List rows = new ArrayList();
    Map row = null;


    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int numColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            row = new HashMap();
            for (int i = 1; i < numColumns + 1; i++) {
                row.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), resultSet.getObject(i));
            }
            rows.add(row);
        }

        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return rows;
}
%>​
```

Comment: oh! you are writing `java` code in `jsp`. :)

Comment: I understand business logic in jsp is not a good process to continue but i need to do it for my project :(

Comment: Is it a `POST` or `GET` request? I would suggest not simply allowing a query to be run from a page in that way. You open yourself up to a lot of security problems.

Comment: i am not sending any user given input  parameter.so i did not use get or post method.i  am only passing an internal string parameter